# How do I turn off grid lines in a datatable being rendered in a Shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to turn off all the grid lines in a table being rendered on a dashboard I'm making. (I'd like to turn off the alternating color as well).

Can anybody help me with this?

I've provided an example below.

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$tbl = renderDT(
            iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output$tbl = renderDT({
            datatable(iris, class = "", options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
        })
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you, guess it was easier than I thought.